# cannot import Python modules on R Studio

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I directly followed the instructions outlined in the website below, to set python virtualenv and install reticulate r package:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023654474-Installing-and-Configuring-Python-with-RStudio

In R Markdown chunk, I tried:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(reticulate)
setwd('/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/')
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "python/bin/python")
````

and

````
```{python}
# import the necessary python packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import math
from scipy.optimize import newton
import torch
from pandas import dataframe
from statistics import mean
````

but I can't import all of the python packages that I want to import (even after installing the modules in my Python virtualenv with the `pip install ...` command). I am getting the error messages below:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘methods.dylib’ not found


Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
  File "/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 58, in <module>
    class RObjectMixin(object):
  File "/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 70, in RObjectMixin
    __show = _get_exported_value('methods', 'show')
  File "/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 44, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hyunjindominiquecho/Desktop/mcmc_intermediate/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 624, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have more than a python version, I use to call **use_python** function from reticulate package to define what python version to use. If it is the case, try this command:

```
use_python("/path/to/python/bin/python3.7", required = T)
```

Change python3.7 to your python version.